# ArcGIS Server spatial query returns geometries only if they intersect all sub-polygon in multipart polygon

Tags: arcgis-server, intersection, spatial-query, multipart, singlepart

Single-part polygon as an input is a common use case of spatial query, it works fine.

However, I am encountering a case that I need to take a multipart polygon as an input to query some point features. At such occasion, ArcGIS service always return me with no feature found, but I can get at least some result features if I do it with multiple queries separately with single-part feature.

Is it possible to query these features as long as that feature is intersecting any one of my multipart geometry?

I may make queries by multipart polygon with >100 parts. Therefore, separate queries is not a solution for me.

---

ArcGIS Server: 10.5.1

ArcGIS JSAPI: 4.19

Requesting Services: Polyline Layer (MapServer)

---

Below is the requests and responses, you may format it at [freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/url-parser-query-string-splitter.html) in order to make it easier to read.

**Request (Query with singlepart polygon)**: https://abc.com/arcgis/rest/services/map-uat/TNM_VIEW/MapServer/15/query?f=json&geometry=%7B%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A2326%2C%22wkid%22%3A102140%7D%2C%22rings%22%3A%5B%5B%5B836437%2C820886%5D%2C%5B836435.535533906%2C820882.464466094%5D%2C%5B836432%2C820881%5D%2C%5B836428.464466094%2C820882.464466094%5D%2C%5B836427%2C820886%5D%2C%5B836428.464466094%2C820889.535533906%5D%2C%5B836432%2C820891%5D%2C%5B836435.535533906%2C820889.535533906%5D%2C%5B836437%2C820886%5D%5D%5D%7D&resultRecordCount=1000&where=1%3D1&outFields=*&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&inSR=102140&outSR=102140

**Response (Query with singlepart polygon)**: 2 features returned

**Request (Query with multipart polygon, first part is the one that I used in above query)**: https://abc.com/arcgis/rest/services/map-uat/TNM_VIEW/MapServer/15/query?f=json&geometry=%7B%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A2326%2C%22wkid%22%3A102140%7D%2C%22rings%22%3A%5B%5B%5B836437%2C820886%5D%2C%5B836435.535533906%2C820882.464466094%5D%2C%5B836432%2C820881%5D%2C%5B836428.464466094%2C820882.464466094%5D%2C%5B836427%2C820886%5D%2C%5B836428.464466094%2C820889.535533906%5D%2C%5B836432%2C820891%5D%2C%5B836435.535533906%2C820889.535533906%5D%2C%5B836437%2C820886%5D%5D%2C%5B%5B842822%2C817308%5D%2C%5B842820.535533906%2C817304.464466094%5D%2C%5B842817%2C817303%5D%2C%5B842813.464466094%2C817304.464466094%5D%2C%5B842812%2C817308%5D%2C%5B842813.464466094%2C817311.535533906%5D%2C%5B842817%2C817313%5D%2C%5B842820.535533906%2C817311.535533906%5D%2C%5B842822%2C817308%5D%5D%5D%7D&resultRecordCount=1000&where=1%3D1&outFields=*&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&inSR=102140&outSR=102140

**Response (Query with multipart polygon)**: no feature returned

Comment: Some more details would make this a better Question. What *exact* query are you doing? To which version of Server? From what client? Can you provide some screenshots?